# Webpack выдает ошибку на import './styles.css'

Tags: webpack

Решил перекочевать из галпа на webpack, и столкнулся с такой ситуацией, вроде следовал руководствуясь с официального сайта!

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open opera",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import $ from "jquery";
import './styles.css';
```

**Summary:**

Когда отключаю файл `import './styles.css';`, то команды `webpack run build` билдится корректно, но как только подключаю обратно `styles.css`, выдает такую ошибку

```
$ npm run build

> my-webpack@1.0.0 build C:\my projects\my-webpack
> webpack --mode production

Hash: b131afefae160f98c63a
Version: webpack 4.31.0
Time: 8171ms
Built at: 2019-05-11 15:19:49
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/index.js 219 bytes {0} [built]
[2] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 521 bytes {0} [built]
[3] ./src/styles.css 279 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(2:1) Unknown word

  1 |
> 2 | var content = require("!!./styles.css");
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];

 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! my-webpack@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-webpack@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const conf = {

  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path:  path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
  devServer: {
    'overlay': true
  },
  module: {
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'style-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = conf;
```

**Project structure**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как выглядит сам файл сss? попробуйте подключить пустой файл css - будет ошибка?

Comment: Приветствую, даже пустой файл выдает ошибку